# How to redirect User to login Screen when not logged in for a Flask App with Azure authorization?

Tags: python, flask, azure-active-directory

I use below example for a web-app which authenticates the User via Azure AD. When entering URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/unprotected I correctly see

> hello world

but entering http://127.0.0.1:5000/protected yields

> {"errors": [{"id": "***", "status": 401, "title": "Missing
> authorization header", "detail": "Ensure your request includes an
> 'Authorization' header and try again"}]}

Is it possible to modify the code so that the user is redirected to a login-page and after logged in sees the correct site showing "hello authenticated and authorised entity"?

```
# https://pypi.org/project/flask-azure-oauth/

from flask import Flask

from flask_azure_oauth import FlaskAzureOauth

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['AZURE_OAUTH_TENANCY'] = '***'
app.config['AZURE_OAUTH_APPLICATION_ID'] = '***'

auth = FlaskAzureOauth()
auth.init_app(app)

@app.route('/unprotected')
def unprotected():
    return 'hello world'

@app.route('/protected')
@auth()
def protected():
    return 'hello authenticated entity'

@app.route('/protected-with-single-scope')
@auth('required-scope')
def protected_with_scope():
    return 'hello authenticated and authorised entity'

@app.route('/protected-with-multiple-scopes')
@auth('required-scope1 required-scope2')
def protected_with_multiple_scopes():
    return 'hello authenticated and authorised entity'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-python&tabs=windows) to log in with the user using identity by Python(Flask app).

**Code:**

```
import identity.web
import requests
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
from flask_session import Session

import app_config

__version__ = "0.7.0"  

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(app_config)
assert app.config["REDIRECT_PATH"] != "/", "REDIRECT_PATH must not be /"
Session(app)

from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_host=1)

auth = identity.web.Auth(
    session=session,
    authority=app.config["AUTHORITY"],
    client_id=app.config["CLIENT_ID"],
    client_credential=app.config["CLIENT_SECRET"],
)


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html", version=__version__, **auth.log_in(
        scopes=app_config.SCOPE, # Have user consent to scopes during log-in
        redirect_uri=url_for("auth_response", _external=True), # Optional. If present, this absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri registered in Azure Portal
        ))


@app.route(app_config.REDIRECT_PATH)
def auth_response():
    result = auth.complete_log_in(request.args)
    if "error" in result:
        return render_template("auth_error.html", result=result)
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    return redirect(auth.log_out(url_for("index", _external=True)))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not (app.config["CLIENT_ID"] and app.config["CLIENT_SECRET"]):
        # This check is not strictly necessary.
        # You can remove this check from your production code.
        return render_template('config_error.html')
    if not auth.get_user():
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template('index.html', user=auth.get_user(), version=__version__)
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

> User is redirected to a login page and after logging in sees the correct site showing "hello authenticated and authorised entity.

After logging in, if you need to show the "hello authenticated and authorised entity" on your site. you can insert the sentence into your index.html.

**Index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample Web App: Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sample Web App</h1>
    <h2>Welcome {{ user.get("name") }}!</h2>
    <h3>Hello authenticated and authorised entity</h3>

    <ul>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]